# Is there an official flight profile of the reentry of the Dragon spacecraft?

Tags: spacex, reentry, dragon-v2, dragon

I wonder whether there's an official plan of the reentry and landing of either the former Dragon spacecraft or the Dragon V2/Crew Dragon, with details like altitudes, velocities, burn length and something. The closest I found was [this plan](https://www.spaceflightinsider.com/missions/human-spaceflight/dm-2-the-flight-plan/) but it doesn't go enough into detail. I'd appreciate if you could show or link me a detailed Dragon reentry plan. Thank you very much.

Comment: I can't help but wonder why so many people insist on asking for SpaceX's proprietary / ITAR data. The cartoonish figures are about all that you will get unless you go to work for SpaceX or NASA. The technologies needed to be able to land on the center of a barge that is not broadcasting "here I am" are **exactly** the same technologies that are needed to make a missile be deadly accurate. The details of the underlying technologies and the detailed plans that use those technologies are highly restricted.

Comment: @DavidHammen They're keeping it for themselves so that no enemy figures out where to shoot their craft with a missile?

Comment: They're keeping to themselves because (a) it is their technology and (b) there are severe penalties in the US law, the International Traffic in Arms Regulations (ITAR), against disclosing "dual use" technologies. Regarding (a), it is their technology: They created these technologies. It is their intellectual property (IP). SpaceX intentionally decided not to use IP law such as patents to protect their technologies as they viewed that doing so would give the IP to China, who SpaceX views as their chief competition. They instead treat their core technologies as carefully guarded trade secrets.

Comment: @DavidHammen But NASA operates these craft too, so they must know. Doesn't NASA tell either? It's a government agency.

Comment: @DavidHammen There's a shuttle reentry profile, just like the one I'd like to find about the Dragon craft. https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-a77574668f6011bb51eeeb117e9d2887

Comment: Regarding (b), "dual use" technologies, SpaceX has repeated shown that the first stage of a spacecraft can be returned to make a pinpoint landing on a barge or back to the launch site. If a bad actor somehow obtained those technologies, that knowledge would help bad actor improve the accuracy of their missiles. Many technologies put to peaceful use in aerospace have the potential to be used for darker purposes. Many of the technologies that SpaceX has invented are subject to huge ITAR penalties, both in terms of monetary penalties and time in jail, should they be divulged.

Comment: @DavidHammen I'm asking for the reentry (and _only_ the reentry/landing) of the _Dragon spacecraft_, not the first stage of the Falcon 9.

Comment: Regarding the comment you made between my two large comments, no NASA does not tell. They are privy to many of SpaceX's trade secrets, and they fully respect those trade secrets. NASA civil servants and contract employees must in general sign a non-disclosure agreement before they can see company proprietary data. The penalties for breaking those agreements are huge and can include jail time.

Comment: @DavidHammen I see. Private companies like SpaceX, Boeing or Blue Origin might keep their crafts' flight profiles secret and oblige NASA to do so too.

Comment: @Giovanni Although some aspects of commercial spacecraft from the ITAR list to the (somewhat) less restrictive EAR list in 2014, many capabilities of spacecraft and the technology in them remain on the ITAR list.  This [MIT Office of Research page](https://research.mit.edu/integrity-and-compliance/export-control/information-documents/my-satellite-itar-or-ear) has more details over what fits in what category. The SpaceX rockets and launchers are definitely under ITAR; the Dragon spacecraft likely will be as well depending on what navigation or other tech is onboard.

Comment: @DavidHammen Publishing an altitude/velocity flight profile -- even of the booster --- would not reveal much about the underlying navigation technology. Possibly, if the data were detailed actual flight data, one might infer points of communication, and some maneuvering capabilities.; but those are by and large known anyway. But Giovanni (and I) would be happy with a general sanitized concept, lacking those real-time details. Public security concerns are a red herring here.

Comment: @DavidHammen And *every* bad actor in the world, me included, can land a drone within 5 meter accuracy these days with tech worth a hundred bucks from the toy store around the corner. Navigation has become trivial. Another red herring.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica This site sees question upon question regarding SpaceX proprietary data go unanswered because the only people who can provide a definitive answer are precluded from doing so. I am not privy to SpaceX's proprietary data, so I can comment on such questions but cannot answer them. If I was privy to such data I could not even comment on such questions. And regarding navigation becoming trivial, thanks for the chuckle.