# Dragon re-entry flight profile?

Tags: reentry, trajectory, dragon-v2, dragon

I was looking online for a profile depicting the Dragon re-entry similar to those showing the launch and first stage re-entry (e.g. https://www.elonx.net/wp-content/uploads/profile_Inspiration4_Infographic_EN.png) but could not find anything.

Ideally that chart would contain time, velocity and altitude information for the different phases of the re-entry.

Is something like that online? (If this has been asked and answered already feel free to flag as dup, but I didn't see anything.)

Comment: @Giovanni Thanks for the correction.

Comment: The question has been asked already but I couldn't find it either. However, the answer was that such chart doesn't exist because these values are to be kept secret from potential enemies, that's how I understood it. Your linked chart doesn't feature altitude either.

Comment: @Giovanni The security argument is funny because any missile would simply be heat-seeking (which would work equally well on ascent and descent). You just have to be somewhere in the weapon's range. (And nation-level adversaries can trivially obtain the data through satellite observation.)

Comment: Yes, it caused me head-shakes too but that's allegedly the reason why there won't be precise charts of Dragon's reentry online.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonic - "Keep from potential enemies" might not mean "protect the capsules from attack"; it might mean "keep secure data that might be useful for devising ICBM re-entry vehicles."  Lots of rocket-related stuff is ITAR-protected and can't be made public.

Comment: @antlersoft Ah, ok, I see. Seems <strike>not</strike> to be rocket science to find that out if you are able to start an icbm with a nuke but yeah. All the pesky differentiation and integration, angles and stuff, it's really not everybody's cup of tea.

Comment: Do we have such charts/profiles in the past (for Dragon and for other capsules, of different designs)? If not, could it be a kind of "trade secrets"?

Comment: @NgPh There are precise reentry charts of Apollo and the Space Shuttle.

Comment: @Giovanni, but none for Soyouz, Shenzou adn other Dragon capsules (?).

Comment: I think I found the similar question https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46177/40257

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In lieu of authoritative data there is always *homebrew simulation*.

The necessary details about Crew Dragon & its entry, short of aerodynamics, are relatively easy to find:

| Parameter | Value | Justification |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Final Orbit | 418 km x 22 km | curve fit of altitude callouts from [Demo-2 splashdown livestream](https://youtu.be/tSJIQftoxeU) |
| Cross-Sectional Area | 12.6 $m^2$ | 4 m diameter circular cross-section [via SpaceX](https://www.spacex.com/vehicles/dragon/) |
| Entry Mass | 9,615 kg | item 4 of [Top 10 Things to Know for NASA’s SpaceX Demo-2 Return](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/top-10-things-to-know-for-nasa-s-spacex-demo-2-return) |
| Orbital Inclination | 51.6° | inclination of ISS |

Critical aerodynamic parameters are the drag coefficient, $C_d$, and the lift to drag ratio, $L/D$. While in general a function of Mach number, these values are (pretty much) invariant in the hypersonic regime (Mach >= 5) and are therefore treated as constant in this simulation.

I was able to infer a drag coefficient from the abstract of [A. A. Gonzales et al., "Mars Sample Return using commercial capabilities: Mission architecture overview"](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6836421/citations?tabFilter=papers) and its [associated presentation](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20140013203) focusing on EDL.

From abstract:

> Total **entry masses** between **7 and 10 mt** were considered

Plot from presentation:

[image: Red dragon Mars entry plot]

Where $\beta$ is the [ballistic coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistic_coefficient) $\beta=\frac{m}{C_D S}$:

| Area, S ($m^2$) | Mass (kg) | $\beta$ ($kg/m^2$) | $C_D$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12.6 | 7,000 | 450 | **1.24** |
| 12.6 | 10,000 | 650 | **1.22** |

Thus $C_D=1.23$ (and $\beta=622$ $kg/m^2$).

The $L/D$ is dependent on the axial displacement of the center of mass of the vehicle (which determines the trim angle of attack) and is configurable prior to entry/flight (I believe Apollo experimented with this in test flights; see $L/D$ differences in flight data from [AS-202](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19670027745) & [Apollo 4](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19690029435)).

The value used in the plot, 0.27, is definitely plausible; however, it is higher than other low-Earth orbit crewed entry capsules ([Soyuz: 0.26](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.proeng.2014.12.550), [Dragon 1: 0.18](https://smartech.gatech.edu/bitstream/handle/1853/26437/107-277-1-PB.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), [Gemini: ~0.15](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19730014059), [Mercury: 0, ballistic](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19710069960)). I used $L/D$ as a fudge factor to make the maximum inertial loading (g-force) about 4.2 g's as [described by Demo-2 astronaut Bob Behnken](https://spaceflightnow.com/2020/08/04/dragon-astronauts-describe-sounds-and-sensations-of-returning-to-earth/). Here is a plot of the (significant) variation of some entry stats based on differing $L/D$ values, with **0.13** being the selected value:

[image: variation of lift to drag ratio]

With all of that out of the way, here is a selection of figures from the simulation (please comment what others you wish to see):

Entry Setup:

[image: entry setup geometry]

Note I have defined entry interface at 120 km (extremes of my atmospheric model), in reality this is sometimes a dynamically sensed condition (g-detect) so the duration may seem a little long (click to enlarge):

[image: trajectory description]

[image: 3D Earth view]

**References:**

- A. A. Gonzales et al., "Mars Sample Return using commercial capabilities: Mission architecture overview," 2014 IEEE Aerospace Conference, 2014, pp. 1-15, [doi: 10.1109/AERO.2014.6836421.](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6836421/citations?tabFilter=papers)
- L. G. Lemke et al."Mars Sample Return Using Commercial Capabilities: Propulsive Entry, Descent and Landing," 2014 IEEE Aerospace Conference, 2014 (retrieved from NTRS [id: 20140013203](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20140013203))
- Xu Guowu et al., Effect of Recession on the Re-entry Capsule Aerodynamic Characteristic, Procedia Engineering, Volume 99, 2015, Pages 377-383, ISSN 1877-7058, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.proeng.2014.12.550.
- Trevino , L. "SpaceX Dragon Re-Entry Vehicle: Aerodynamics and Aerothermodynamics with Application to Base Heat-Shield Design," 6th International Planetary Probe Workshop Conference Proceedings, 2008 ([Georgia Tech link](https://smartech.gatech.edu/bitstream/handle/1853/26437/107-277-1-PB.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y))
- Whitnah, A. M. & Howes, D. B. "Summary analysis of the Gemini entry aerodynamics," 1972 (retrieved from NTRS [id: 19730014059](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19730014059))
- Brown, S. W. & Moseley, W. C., Jr. "Summary of wind-tunnel investigations of the static longitudinal stability characteristics of the production Mercury configurations at Mach numbers from 0.05 to 20," 1961 (retrieved from NTRS [id: 19710069960](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19710069960))

Comment: Wow. This is not just a hobby, right?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica unfortunately it is just a hobby, for now :(

Comment: So much for keeping the real data secret because, you know, that prevents evil actors from designing re-entry. I see.

Comment: Interesting that risk assessment didn't find fault with a trajectory squarely aiming at Tallahassee. Apparently, 200 km or so are enough of a safety margin. One argument may be that the debris from a disintegrating capsule would hit the ground earlier, not later.